# How to push Vapor 2 Swift 4 project to Heroku

Tags: swift, heroku, xcode9, vapor

Using Xcode 9 and Swift 4 as well as `vapor heroku push` / `vapor heroku init`, I receive:

```
-----> Swift app detected
Cloning into 'swiftenv'...
Swift 3 Heroku Installer
  Version: 3.1.1
  Operating System: ubuntu1404
 Installing Swiftenv
Cloning into '/app/.swiftenv'...
 Installing Swift
Downloading https://swift.org/builds/swift-3.1.1-release/ubuntu1604/swift-3.1.1-RELEASE/swift-3.1.1-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04.tar.gz
/tmp/swiftenv-3.1.1- /tmp/build_d
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
/tmp/build_d
3.1.1 has been installed.
✅  Done
-----> Installing clang-3.7.0
precompile
-----> Building Package ... this will take a while
swift-build: error: Package requires minimum Swift tools version 4.0.0. Current Swift tools version is 3.1.0
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Swift app.
 !     Push failed
```

In the `Package.swift` file it says:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "name",
    products: [
        .library(name: "App", targets: ["App"]),
        .executable(name: "Run", targets: ["Run"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "2.1.0")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-provider.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "1.2.0")),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "App", dependencies: ["Vapor", "FluentProvider"],
                exclude: [
                    "Config",
                    "Public",
                    "Resources",
                ]),
        .target(name: "Run", dependencies: ["App"]),
        .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: ["App", "Testing"])
    ]
)
```

Other than that it is literally the initial api template project. What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Try to comment out `swift-tools-version:4.0` on the top.

Comment: That is unfortunately not enough, as there are other breaking syntax changes between the version 3 and 4 of Package.swift.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The project template was recently updated to require Swift 4, but the Heroku buildpack still installs Swift 3.1.1 by default. Until the template is updated to resolve this situation, do this:

1. Create a file called `.swift-version` in your project root with `4.0` inside.
2. Commit and push to Heroku.

The buildpack will now install Swift 4 and your project will compile.

### Update (2017-11-13)

I have updated the buildpack, therefore the steps above are no longer necessary.
New applications and pushes without a pinned version will use Swift 4.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

Above answer is perfect, I just try to simplify for those who might get confused (like me :D) and having question How to ?

Go to your project root directory.

1. Create swift-version like

   - $ touch .swift-version
2. Open that file

   - $ open .swift-version

     write 4.0
3. save that file

Done :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly install swift 4.0, then set it as builder.

```
swiftenv install 4.0
swiftenv local 4.0
```

ref: https://github.com/kylef/heroku-buildpack-swift

Comment: what do you mean with `install swift 4` and also: where to `set it as builder`? i know you want your answer to be helpful for future readers. but with like 6 words it really is not.